# R date conversion issue

Tags: r, date, format, character

I'm trying to convert my date column from character to date format, which I thought should be dead easy using:

```
datetest <- as.Date(CAT$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

but it returns:

> Error in as.Date.default(CAT$Date, "%Y-%m-%d") :    do not know how to
>   convert 'CAT$Date' to class “Date”

I have also tried: `datetest <- as.Date(CAT[["Date"]], "%Y-%m-$d")`
but get the same error message.

Really not sure why it doesn't like it, any help to a complete newbie would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Coul you please show a couple of values from this column?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.Currently I have the column populated with the date correctly, but in character format, for example the first values is: 2016-09-20, second value 2016-09-21 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

first check the class of CAT$Date, then do the following:

```
datetest <- as.Date(as.character(unlist(CAT$Date)), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The class is "dataTables_scrollBody", at least I think.. I right clicked, inspect and then at the pointer it reads ' div class = "dataTables_scrollBody" '

Comment: Also to add, I am really trying to get at reformatting the column in the data frame, not just into a new vector, i.e. my original line should've been: CAT$Date <- as.Date(CAT$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")